# SQL Server : Appending VARBINARY slow performance

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am appending bytes of a file into a VARBINARY field into a SQL Server Database using iterations of 64KB.

However, I believe its bringing the whole byte object back into memory, appending the bytes and then updating the row which is causing a downgrade of performance

The SQL statement that I am using to update the VARBINARY field

```
long milliseconds = DateTime.Now.Ticks; 

ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.table SET Item = Item + @item WHERE id = @id", new SqlParameter("@item", append), new SqlParameter("@id", id));

long millisecondsAfter = DateTime.Now.Ticks;

long timeTook = millisecondsAfter - milliseconds;
```

The reason why I say this because the the milliseconds (TimeTook) value is greater after every loop.

So the question is, is there a faster way and obviously a more efficient way of doing the query above?

**---Edit (Answer)---**

Thanks to tbe below answers, this is the new Query which works a lot better

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET Item.WRITE(@item, NULL, 0) WHERE id = @id", new SqlParameter("@item", append), new SqlParameter("@id", id));
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the `id` column indexed?

Comment: No, but this is happening on updating only one row in the table and normally indexing helps with searching mostly.

Comment: The behavior you describe is the way SQL Server changes data - it always pull the data from the disk to the memory cache and updates it there, then writes it back to the disk.  The best way to increase performance is make all the changes at once rather than using a loop.

Comment: Actually no. It is the way it changes data when the programmer avoids using the proper syntax to update a part of a blog. Granted, most people do not know that, but it is there.

Comment: That is true assuming his field is varbinary(max), and not varbinary(n).

Comment: HOw would you do "iterations of 64KB" over a varbianary(n)?

Comment: You don't :)  Point conceded.

Comment: @user3428422, you should know that indexing often helps in updates, deltes and inserts (that use the select staement for the values) particulaly if there are any joins. It may also slow some of those down depending on what is being done and how many indexes need to be adjusted. Indexes are not just for selects.

Comment: Yeah I understand and you and Beargle are correct. But I was trying to get away from indexing for this particular problem as I have been testing with only one row currently in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically what happens when people do not read the documentation.

You can directly do a partial update via SQL with no need to load the whole object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

is the syntax for the update statement. Please note the ".Write".

Let me quote;

> .WRITE (expression,@Offset,@Length) Specifies that a section of the
>   value of column_name is to be modified. expression replaces @Length
>   units starting from @Offset of column_name. Only columns of
>   varchar(max), nvarchar(max), or varbinary(max) can be specified with
>   this clause. column_name cannot be NULL and cannot be qualified with a
>   table name or table alias.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not optimize the binary append case here. Indeed, this leads to quadratic performance. (One could argue that SQL Server *should* optimize this.)

Use the [`WRITE` clause of the `UPDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) statement to achieve streaming writes and stable performance.